# Apply css in dynamic injected html

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, dom

I am doing something like StackOverflow editor. Fetch markdown text, transfer it to HTML, and inject it into the preview area. But when I tried to apply CSS to the injected HTML elements, it was ignored. In browser inspection, I can not find the stylesheet I write for the elements. I guess this is about the order of CSS rendering. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="item">
      <label for="content">Contents</label>
      <textarea name="content" id="content" v-model="mdtext"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="preview"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import marked from 'marked'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      mdtext: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    mdtext: function () {
      document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = marked(this.mdtext)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
...
#preview p{
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
...
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add Vue to category list it is regarding Vue.js

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the html element location in dev tools?

Comment: it is not registered because the p tag is not receiving the exact suffix generated by the dom

Comment: this might not be the exact way to inject html

Comment: also check the place where the p tag style is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `scoped` css, which makes Vue add that `data-v-` attribute to the `p` as well. However, the generated `<p>` doesn't not have that same `data-v-` attribute, which is why it's not working.
You can easily fix it by using the deep selector:

```
<style scoped>
#preview >>> p {

}
</style>
```

Reference: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors